# How to use page.filter(test_function) in PDFPlumber library?

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-parsing, pdf-extraction

I am trying to delete tables inside the a pdf page and I'm trying to use **page.filter()** function for that, here I have table **bbox coordinates**  and I am trying to compare if object coordinates are inside the table coordinates or not.
But I was unable to find any sample usage for filter function.

here is the [documentation link](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber#python-library)

I tried in this way :

```
def filter_func(object):
  #some logic to find the coordinates inside boundary or not

new_page = page.filter(lambda x: x if filter_func(x) else '')
```

but this usage is not working unfortunately, please help in knowing how to use page.filter function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this which is working:

```
def filter_func(object):
 #some logic to find the coordinates inside boundary or not

new_page = page.filter(filter_func)
```

page.filter is a generator and only executes when you use new_page